# R if statement error: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Tags: r, if-statement, replace

I have this data set which looks something like this:

[image: I have this data set which looks something like this.]

This is the error I got:

[image: This is the error I got]

This is my code

```
read <- read.csv("sample.csv")

text2 <- read$text2
if(text2 == "No concern" | text2 == "No concern." | text2 == "No concerned" | text2 == "No concerns." | text2 == "No concerns") {
  read$emotion <- "unknown"
  read$polarity <- "neutral"
}else 
{
  read$emotion = emotion
  read$polarity = polarity
}

write.csv(text2, file = "test1.csv", row.names = TRUE)
```

I actually thought of using if or if else statements to change the emotions and polarity in the csv file (see picture attached). The reason why I want to change the emotion and polarity is because some are not correct. So for example if under text2, it is "no concern", "no concerns", or "no concerned" it's emotion should be unknown and  polarity should be neutral.

Can someone please help??

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. In particular, use `dput` to show the contents of `read`.

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement isn't vectorized. `help("if")` does say on `cond` in `if (cond) expr`

> A length-one logical vector that is not NA. Conditions of length greater than one are accepted with a warning, but only the first element is used. Other types are coerced to logical if possible, ignoring any class.

You can try something using `ifelse()` for vectors:

```
ifelse (text2 %in% c("No concern", "No concern.", "No concerned", "No concerns.", "No concerns"),
{read$emotion <- "unknown"; read$polarity <- "neutral"},
{read$emotion <- read$emotion; read$polarity <- read$polarity}
)
```

(Not run due to missing data)

---

#### EDIT: `data.table` version:

```
library(data.table)
read <- fread("sample.csv")
read[text2 %like% "^No concern", emotion := "unknown"]
read[text2 %like% "^No concern", polarity := "neutral"]
```

`text2 %like% "^No concern"` selects all rows of `read` which start with "No concern". Only for those rows the contents of columns `emotion` and `polarity` is changed. All other rows will stay as they were.

> NB: If performance matters, the last two statements could be combined into a single assignment statement.

```
read[text2 %like% "^No concern", c("emotion", "polarity") := list("unknown", "neutral"]
```